# NSTimer updates label every second but overwrites previous label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm using an NSTimer to update a countdown label every second ("5 seconds ..." then "4 seconds ... " etc) but each time the label is updated, it overwrites the previous output:

[image]

This is the method for updating the label, which will run every second until the 5-second countdown ends:

```
- (void)timerRun {
UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc] init];
test.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds", secondsCount];
[self.audioPicker.view addSubview:test];

if (secondsCount == 0) {
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
}

    secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
}
```

I've tried setting the label back to nil or blank at the beginning of the loop, but I'm clearly doing something wrong. How do I make it so the labels don't overwrite each other like this?

Comment: You keep creating new labels when you should just create one label before the timer loop starts and then in the timer loop only update the text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a label outside of timerRun

only update the text inside of the method

```
// make sure the label is initialed before use
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *test;

- (void)timerRun {
    test.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds", secondsCount];
    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownTimer = nil;
    }
    secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont create the label inside of your method.

This will create a label at each call.

Instead declare it at the class level

Answer (score 1):

Create label outside of timerRun method as it keeps on creating label as timerRun is called

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
UILabel *test ;// instance variable
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
      text = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0,200.0, 150.0,200.0)];// use your frame dimensions
      test.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds", secondsCount];
      [self.audioPicker.view addSubview:test];
}
- (void)timerRun 
{

   test.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds", secondsCount];

  if (secondsCount == 0) 
  {
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
  }

    secondsCount--;
}
```